# Getting desired result twice instead of once

Tags: c#, .net

Apologies for the incorrect terminology, I'm still becoming familiar with the .NET Framework and programming in general, and that makes it very hard to ask a specific question. That aside I'm trying to code something that will open a program then report back to me via WriteLine when it's closed, now for whatever reason when the application is first launched it reports to me as closed, then the program opens and is closed and then is reported to be closed again. To reiterate I only want it to report to me after the application has been initially opened. Thanks in advance! Here's my code:

```
class MyProcess : Process
    {

        public void WhenExited()
        {
            OnExited();
        }

    }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyProcess Updates = new MyProcess();
            Updates.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "updater.exe");
            MyProcess p = new MyProcess();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "program.exe");
            p.Start();
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_HasExited);
            p.WaitForInputIdle();
            p.WhenExited();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

             void myProcess_HasExited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Process has exited.");
            }
            // Exit Controll
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            while (answer != "Exit")
            {
                answer = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you inherit from `Process` and calling `OnExited` yourself?

Comment: I was going off some example code provided in the MSDN Library, is that the issue?

Comment: What do you think happens when you do `p.WhenExited()` ?

Comment: Ah! You know I've been staring at this code for like an hour pondering this, and I didn't even think about that. Thank you so much! Really appreciate your time!